# multiple 3D text shadow using css

Tags: css

I want to give shadow effect to some of my texts in a website which would make it look like 3D using CSS Is it possible?

Answer (score 17):

Yeah, it's possible to have multiple `text-shadow`s on a font, just use a comma-separated list of values:

```css
p {
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em #ccc, 0.2em 0.2em 0.3 em #ddd /* ...other...*/
}
```

Comment: Which gets on top of the other?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

http://jsfiddle.net/RobertKolatzek/uk2my/1/

and try to understand, how it works (colors, sizes, etc).

At bottom, you get your text-shadow property to copy and paste.

In a simple case, you use text-shadow to render 3D, then the shadow of it:

```
text-shadow: 0px 4px 0 #ccc, 0px 6px 0 #888;
```